# Formatting cells as percentage

Tags: excel, vba

In VBA, how can I format a range as percentage? The numbers within is a decimal number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is write:

```
Sub FormatToPercentage()

Selection.NumberFormat = "0.00%"

End Sub
```

Comment: If this works, please check the answer to accept it. ^^ BTW, you can fiddle around with the "0.00%" part to match the type of format you want (play around with the macro recorder to see the different ways to write it).

Comment: Thx a bunch :) I knew it had to be simple.